# Редактирование данных в recycler view

Tags: android, recyclerview

Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу сделать возможность редактирования `item`'a в списке `RecyclerView`.

Как я понимаю, нужно изменить `item` и уведомить адаптер об этом. Для изменения `item`'а я планирую передавать данные в другую `Activity`, и по завершении редактирования возвращаться в адаптер.

Для того, что бы я смог воспользоваться методом `startActivityForResult`, я должен в наследоваться в адаптере от `AppCompatActivity`, что не возможно, т.к. я уже наследуюсь от `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterPart.ViewHolder>`.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Для того, что бы я смог воспользоваться методом `startActivityForResult`, я должен в наследоваться в адаптере от `AppCompatActivity`

Наследовать класс адаптера от класса `activity` – весьма странная идея. Адаптер – это адаптер, `activity` – это `activity`. Это совершенно разные классы.

Вы можете вызвать метод `startActivityForResult`, например, передавая в адаптер `Context`:

```
MyAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

А потом с помощью него вызывать нужный метод:

```
((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE);
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, работает. А почему не нужно наследоваться от AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @Александр, Потому что класс у Вас представляет собой адаптер, а не `activity`.